# Why can I getIdentifier of mp3 file in raw but not programmatically and how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, resources

I've started to develop an Android app and I'm very new about this.
My app has to read some QR code and at the moment I'm using the zxing library.
Now I've got some issue into a part of the application that involves playing sounds stored into the /res/raw:

my code sometimes runs.. but most of times it doesn't

I can access some sound files in raw folder with this code:

```
var myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.filename)
```

but not calling the file I need through a variable:

```
var myVarWithFilenameInside: String = "filename"        
var myFileInt: Int = resources.getIdentifier("$myVarWithFilenameInside", "raw", this.getPackageName())
var myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, myFileInt)
```

(even if apparently at "random" this seems to occasionally work; it's pretty strange indeed..)

I tried already to not specify the type of variable and also to insert packageName (as suggested by the IDE) instead of this.getPackageName()... However nothing seems to work

PS.
also this instruction works perfectly, but again I have to obtain the identifier without using a variable but putting it inside the method manually

```
var myFileInt: Int = resources.getIdentifier("filename", "raw", this.getPackageName())
var myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, myFileInt)
```

I've got very stuck with this... So any kind of help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by programmatically? Both are programmatic. You can't use the second method for any random filename or path. If there's a file that isn't inside your app's raw folder, you need to use the DocumentsProvider.

Comment: I meant in the working case I must set a long list of if statements so that if a string contains the wanted file (all of them are into /Res/raw) then it triggers the right statement with the filename made explicit.

Comment: But what I need is to store the chosen filename into a var, getting the identifier then create a media player object that points at the file I need.

Comment: I don't know why the same file is correctly addressed if I call it by its filename (see the main post), but it gives me a IOException of file not found if I try to call it using a variable.

Comment: I updated the question trying to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a file **filename.mp3** in the **raw** folder, this is working for me:

```
var myVarWithFilenameInside = "filename"
var myFileInt: Int = resources.getIdentifier(myVarWithFilenameInside, "raw", this.packageName)
var myPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@YourActivity, myFileInt)
myPlayer.start()
```